# What's the benefit of refreshtoken over the accesstoken?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, refresh-token

I am learning the stateless jwt authentication concept and experimenting the implementation of the process in nodejs server side.

I am very confused about the refresh token. I don't see any benefit than only use one access token.

I can simply implement the access token with following method:

1. the access token living for **10 hours**
2. if the user use the access token, and the **expire time less than 1 hour**, then, I issue the user **a new access token**.

People say, the refresh token is safer, but I don't why. You save the access token and refresh token both on your computer either in cookies or localstorage, if a "thief" can get your access token, he can also get your refresh token. I don't see any security benefit with refresh token. It makes only the process unnecessary complicated.

Why this concept is still so popular?

Answer (score 1):

[Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) has a nice article on that. In short, you can store the access token wherever you want, since it doesn't matter if it gets leaked or if someone intercepts a request where you use it.

But the refresh token needs to be stored in a safe location, and could be blacklisted by the server if it has been compromised.

Comment: But I can also save the access token in a very good place, the same good as the refresh token...

Comment: @xirururu Yes, that is true. Another aspect I didn't mention is the idea of a separated Auth and Resource server. The auth server issues the tokens and generates new access tokens based on a refresh token. The resource server however stores the actual data. In a traditional token setup, it would send each request it gets to the auth server to validate it and then, depending on that result, block the request or fetch the requested data. But using an access token signed by the auth server, the resource server can validate the token without a request to the auth server, reducing respone time.

Comment: You can separate the auth server and resource server freely also with access token. Maybe the question is too opinion-based. But I really doubt the security improvement of the refresh token.